# JavaScript Accordion script with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am not a JavaScript programmer but I am needing to use it for editing my organization's website.

The page consists of parent accordions with nested accordions and listed items within the nested accordion.

I want to be able to style the parent accordion a different way than the nested accordion to differentiate between the two; so, for example, having the nested accordion be a different color than the parent accordion.

The code works as is for the most part, but I'm having a problem where the content within one parent accordion is not correctly interacting with the content form anther parent accordion.

First Problem:
When I first load the page and then expand the top parent accordion, then expand    the nested accordions, the bottom-most listed items will sink behind the next parent accordion and be obscured.  If I then contract the nested accordions and then expand them again, the listed items then interact correctly with the parent accordion below.

Second Problem:
This second issue is how to properly style the two accordions differetntly.  I have tried a couple of different ways to perhaps solve this. One way is to create a secondary script that calls:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("nest");
```

And then gave the nested accordions with the class name "nest."

Another is to chain my CSS for my nested accordions.  Using - button.accordion - for the parent accordions and then - div.panel button.accordion - for the nested accordions.

Any guidance on how to properly go about either of these two issues?  This is my first time posting to stackoverflow so I apologize if I've made any faux pas in my post.

The accordion script used was pulled straight from w3schools.com

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      parent.style.maxHeight = parseInt(parent.style.maxHeight) +
        panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- first accordion section -->
<!-- first parent accordion -->
<button class="accordion">Name of Parent Accordion</button>
<div class="panel">
  <!-- first nested accordion -->
  <button class="accordion">Name of Nested Accordion</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- second nested accordion -->
  <button class="accordion">Name of Nested Accordion</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- second accordion section -->
<!-- second parent accordion -->
<button class="accordion">Name of Parent Accordion</button>
<div class="panel">
  <!-- first nested accordion -->
  <button class="accordion">Name of Nested Accordion</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Classes are your friend here, don't be afraid to use them. They can be used to identify levels and will make your life easier. I.e, `class='accordion parent'` or `class='accordion nested'`

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment.  I have attempted to use multiple classes in this instance to identify the different levels of accordions, but I have yet to figure out how to correctly incorporate them into my JS.

Comment: This perhaps shows my inexperience but I didn't realize you could name classes as: class='accordion parent' and class='accordion nested' and then call them in CSS accordion.parent and accordion.nested.  Learn something new everyday, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>



<!-- first accordion section -->
<!-- first parent accordion -->
<button class="accordion">Name of Parent Accordion</button>
<div class="panel">
  <!-- first nested accordion -->
  <button class="accordion">Name of Nested Accordion</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- second nested accordion -->
  <button class="accordion">Name of Nested Accordion</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- second accordion section -->
<!-- second parent accordion -->
<button class="accordion">Name of Parent Accordion</button>
<div class="panel">
  <!-- first nested accordion -->
  <button class="accordion">Name of Nested Accordion</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried using this script but it doesn't seem to allow me to expand my parent accordions.

Comment: After working with it some more this seems to solve my problem, thank you so much.